# Check if my webhook has been requested

Tags: php, ajax, webhooks

I'm integrating the Mollie Api in my website.

Users can create a payment on my website.
After submitting the payment they get send to an 3rd party website.
If they have finished the payment on the 3rd party website, the 3rd party website sends an asynchronus request to my webhook page **'payment-verification.php'**.
At this moment i'm writing a new file to my website root everytime the page gets requested, but no files have been created..

So my question is: How do i check if my webhook has been requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your web server is configured correctly, your web server logs will tell you whether the page was request. Search your logs for 'payment-verification.php'.

Look for any HTTP responses that indicate a failure, such as 404 (Not Found) or 500 (Internal Server Error).

If the logs contain a 200 (OK) response, you will need to debug your PHP script to determine why it is not writing files when executed.